# Call a function of parent aspx page from web user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a aspx page on it i'm dynamically adding the web user controls in a placeholder. and know i have cancel button on the one user control and on click of that Cancel button i want to load other user control inside the aspx page (placeholder).

how can i do that, if i create an event handler in usercontrol then that become null.

thanks

Comment: Can you show some code for where you dynamically add your usercontrol to the page.

Comment: Your controls should not have any knowledge of your pages - this would create tight coupling where there shouldn't be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A user control should never, ever have any kind of dependency to the page where it lives. Add an event to the control and fire it from the Cancel button event handler.

```
public event EventHandler CancelClicked;

protected Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(CancelClicked != null)
  {
    CancelClicked(this, e);
  }
}
```

From your page, subscribe to the controls's CancelClicked event and do whatever operation should be done on that other user control.

Comment: @Anders Abel i already have done this, in my case debugger never entered inside the if(CancelClicked != null)
  {
    CancelClicked(this, e);
  }
this code because my cancelclicked is always null

Comment: When you add the control to the page, you have to subscribe to the event handler with `OnCancelClicked`. The control definition should look like `<mycontrol id="MyControl" OnCancelClicked="MyControl_CancelClicked"/>`

Comment: @AndersAbel He's adding them dynamically.

Comment: If added dynamically, you have to assign the event handler in the code: `myControl.CancelClicked += MyControl_CancelClicked;`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way to achieve this would to create an event in the user control that is fired when you need it to communicate, then in the page you can subscribe to this event.

**Your User Control**

Put this in your control as an event variable.

```
public event EventHandler CancelRequested;
```

Then in the cancel button click event :

```
CancelRequested(this, new CommandEventArgs("CancelClicked", SomeVariable));
```

**Your Page (or parent)**

Then subscribe to the event in the parent page like this (when you dynamically add it in):

```
ctrlYourControl.CancelRequested += new EventHandler(ctrlYourControl_CancelRequested);
```

Declare the event handler :

```
void ctrlYourControl_CancelRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // display other user control
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting, when you type the ctrlYourControl.CancelRequested you can press tab tab and the rest will be done automatically.

Comment: i already have done this, in my case when debugging reached at CancelRequested(this, new CommandEventArgs("CancelClicked", SomeVariable));
 it give null reference

Comment: +1 for the use of CommandEventArgs to pass some useful information.

Answer (score 2):

Add this event to your user controls:

```
public event EventHandler CancelClicked;
```

Now, this method on your parent aspx page.

```
public void OnCancelClicked (object sender, EventArgs data)  
{  
    // do your stuffs like loading other controls and
    // whatever when event fired
}
```

When you are loading your user control dynamically, add this:

```
var someControl = LoadControl(@"~\SomeControl.ascx") as SomeControl;
someControl.CancelClicked += new EventHandler(OnCancelClicked);
```

And on your user controls:

```
public void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(CancelClicked != null)
    {
        CancelClicked(this, e);
    }
}
```

This should do !